# how to prevent hadoop corrupted .gz file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using following simple code to upload files to hdfs.

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(src, dst);
```

The files are generated by webserver java component and rotated and closed by logback in .gz format. I've noticed that sometimes the .gz file is corrupted.

```
 > gunzip logfile.log_2013_02_20_07.close.gz 
 gzip: logfile.log_2013_02_20_07.close.gz: unexpected end of file
```

But the following command does show me the content of the file

```
> hadoop fs -text /input/2013/02/20/logfile.log_2013_02_20_07.close.gz
```

The impact of having such files is quite disaster - since the aggregation for the whole day fails, and also several slave nodes is marked as blacklisted in such case.

What can I do in such case?
Can hadoop copyFromLocalFile() utility corrupt the file?
Does anyone met similar problem ?

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem on Amazon EMR and thought it was an EMR issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't do - this error is normally associated with GZip files which haven't been closed out when originally written to local disk, or are being copied to HDFS before they have finished being written to.

You should be able to check by running an md5sum on the original file and that in HDFS - if they match then the original file is corrupt:

```
hadoop fs -cat /input/2013/02/20/logfile.log_2013_02_20_07.close.gz | md5sum
md5sum /path/to/local/logfile.log_2013_02_20_07.close.gz
```

If they don't match they check the timestamps on the two files - the one in HDFS should be modified after the local file system one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how can I check the validity of .gz file itself (without opening the whole file)? With java client API ?

Comment: Unforntunately you can't really - GZip isn't a splittable format, meaning that you can't just seek to a random position in the file and recover the stream. For this reason you have to start from the beginning of the file when checking validity

Comment: Thank again. First of all i've found the root cause of the problem - I had two machines that executed concurrently the same uploading from the same shared storage folder (some vip it problems). I'm adding the code to prevent such thing (with file locking). In addition I've found that gunzip -t can test the gzip file. You rihgt the gz is defenetelly not good (althouhg I have a small files - less than 64M block) I want to change all .gz to snappy compression, and merge small files to bigger but I need to check it and evaluate, maybe look for some already exists utility